# Jupyter Notebook, NameError: is not defined, %%time prevents assignment

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, unassigned-variable

I came across a very strange bug running a Jupyter Notebook (IPython:  7.4.0) where a variable was not assigned as normally.  It took me quite bit of time to figure out the cause, searching in vain all over, variable scope, type conversion and TensorFlow intricacies ;(

In fact, using %%time cell magic was preventing assignment of the variable in the cell. Therefore the assigned variable was not defined in the cell below giving a characteristic error message: "NameError: 'xxx' is not defined."

It seems to be a [known issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11659), hoping that can help someone else.

Comment: I'm a little puzzled by the issue discussion.  I thought it was normal that variables assigned in a `timeit block, line or cell, would be local.  I don't want the results of a 1000 iterations of some 'append' action to contaminate my main workspace.  But then I'm looking at this as a console user, not a notebook one.

Comment: @hpaulj I agree with you, but not everyone has your knowledge and understanding of iPython Notebook and they deserve to be helped anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is simple, just remove %%time from the cell.

Rather use:

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from datetime import timedelta

start = timer()

# Process
# ...


end = timer()
print ("Execution time HH:MM:SS:",timedelta(seconds=end-start))
```

Source: [Stackoverflow - Measure time elapsed in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55239060/1209842)